# Poisson process with rate a

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I got a task and I have no idea how to solve it:

Task: During the time 'T' number of events 'A' is a random variable distributed according to Poisson's law with the parameters $$a*T$$
Find a probability, that the time between two events 'A' will be not more than 't'.

Having: a = 0.13; t = 1.37

My solution:
I know that Poisson distribution is commonly used to model rate of random events that occur in some fixed time interval. In my opinion, we can use a 'exponential distribution' with a parameter 'lambda' = a is less than or equal to t:

P(time between two events 'A'<= t) = P(Exponential(lambda = a) <= t)

Thus,
$$P(Exponential(lambda = a) <= t) = 1 - e^{(-at)}$$

Then, substituting the values of a and t, we get:
$$P(time between two events 'A' <= 1.37) = 1 - e^{(-0.13 * 1.37)} = 0.163141$$

I am not sure is my solution correct.

Comment: Please try and format your question properly using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is called a *[Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)* with rate $a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to properly argue is as below:-

$$\{\text{Time between two events is less than}\, t\}=\{\text{No events in time period }\, t\}^{c} $$ .

Now if the number of events in time period $T$ (call it $N(T)$) is Poisson distributed with mean $a\cdot T$ .

Then the probability that there is no event in time period $t$ is $P(N(t)=0)=\exp({-a t})$

Thus the $$P(\{\text{Time between two events is less than}\, t\})=1-P(N(t)=0)=1-\exp(-a t)$$

Comment: Your provided explanation seems to be more constructive, but the way I provided my solution, in a nutschell, is correct?

Comment: @OlgierdJankovski Well , it is difficult to understand what you are writing. Maybe if you format it correctly then more things will be clear

Comment: @OlgierdJankovski In any case, when you have a Poisson Process, the time between two events is called the Interarrival time and it is Exponentially distributed. I have just basically shown in short on why it is so .

Comment: True, I am struggling with the poisson's distribution, I gonna pay some extra attention to that, sorry for the confusion

Comment: No issues. What I have actually done is justify your claim that the time between two events is exponentially distributed.

Comment: Also @OlgierdJankovski You don't need to worry. You'll find that Poisson is one of the "nicest" and well behaved discrete distributions. Also exponential is fun to work with. With time , you'll also find that the Poisson Process is the one of the easiest amongst continuous time Markov Processes. So don't worry too much. I'm sure you'll end up loving it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the support tho! Over time I am starting to understand discrete distributions. Feeling sorry for the 'desmos' app, because this one has to handle all my calculations